# Regex to check if string is alphanumeric separated by commas or a single alphanumeric string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have the following right now which works fine if the string is alphanumeric and separated by commas, but it doesn't work if I only have a single string.

`"^([a-zA-Z0-9]+,)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"`

Works for something like "1A,1B,1C", doesn't work on "1A"

Sorry, I don't know much about regex and I only got this through searching.

Here are a few example of what can be valid or invalid

`1` - Valid

`12` - Valid

`1A` - Valid

`A1` - Invalid

`12A` - Valid

`A12` - Invalid

`1AA` - Invalid

`A` - Invalid

`1,2,3,6A,6B,11,11A` - Valid

Invalid would be if any other characters appear in the string except for numbers and letters also no commas or anything in the prefix and suffix

Comment: You should tell us what your goal is. What strings do you want to match with? What strings should not match it?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd mmm... didn't think about looking in to getting a more concrete regex for what I need. My inputs will be a single digit number or 2 digits or a single or 2 digit number with 1 letter. "1, 2, 3, 11, 6A, 6B, 11C, 11D" like those. Inputs can be multiple separated by comma or just one. "11" or "10, 11A, 11B"

Comment: You could still improve this question by adding some specific non-matching examples. For example, would 'ABCD' match?

Comment: is you want to say `[any Number] + [ alphanumeric or comma]* +[alphanumeric]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^\d{1,2}[A-Z]?(?:,\d{1,2}[A-Z]?)*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/25

Comment: I don't think 4 digits and then a letter should match: `1234A`

Comment: OP's comment: `My inputs will be a single digit number or 2 digits or a single or 2 digit number with 1 letter.`

Answer (score 1):

This regex will work for you [Test Given Regex](https://regex101.com/r/sZ4cV5/1)

```
^\d{1,2}+[a-zA-Z]?+(?:,\d{1,2}+[a-zA-Z]?)*$
```

> Define `^\d{1,2}+[a-zA-Z]?`

```
 \d          : Represent a digit 0-9 
 {1,2}       : Minimum 1 and Maximum 2 Of previous Expressions
 \d{1,2}     : Means 1 to two digits
 +           : Previous Expression Repeats From one to unlimited times
 [a-zA-Z]    : Range Defined for all capital And Small latter [a-z] for small Latter, [A-Z] Capital: latter
 ?           : Repeat Previous Expression 0 or one Times
 [a-zA-Z]?   : One/Zero Charter from "a to z ,A to Z"
```

> `^\d{1,2}+[a-zA-Z]?` : Start with one or two digits and an optional character
>
> Define `(?:,\d{1,2}+[a-zA-Z]?)*$`

```
 ?:          : Non Capturing Group,Match zero to unlimited times//Reference link given Below
 ,           : Match Comma(Given Character must be comma)
 \d          : Represent a digit 0-9 
 {1,2}       : Minimum 1 and Maximum 2 Of previous Expressions
 \d{1,2}     : Means 1 to two digits
 +           : Previous Expression Repeats From one to unlimited times
 [a-zA-Z]    : Range Defined for all capital And Small latter [a-z] for small Latter, [A-Z] Capital: latter
 ?           : Repeat Previous Expression 0 or one Times
 [a-zA-Z]?   : One/Zero Charter from "a to z ,A to Z"
 *           : Match Previous Expression Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible
 $           : End of Regex
```

> `(?:,\d{1,2}+[a-zA-Z]?)*$` : Start with comma then one or two number/digitd then one character from range `a-zA-Z` **This Expression Match from 0 to ultimate times** and the end of regex
>
> `^\d{1,2}+[a-zA-Z]?+(?:,\d{1,2}+[a-zA-Z]?)*$` : Start with (one or two) Digit , Followed by one character,
>    Start next expression (one comma 1-2 digits and an optional Character ) and match it 0 to unlimited times as meany times as possible Before End of string

1. [Check online Regex Test](https://regex101.com/r/sZ4cV5/1)
2. Reference : [Non Capturing Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group)